Exchangeability in terms of permutations in card theory, Ethier (2010).
Exchangeability in terms of permutations in card theory, Ethier (2010).
I am experiencing doubt with reconciling the standard definition of exchangeability with the way Ethier (2010), in Doctrine of Chances: Probabilistic Aspects of Gambling presents a model for a well-shuffled deck of cards.
Context.
Assume we have a deck of 52 distinct cards, individually labelled with the numbers 1 - 52 in natural order,
$$\begin{aligned}
\text{card label}:\  (&1, 2, \dots, 52) \\
\text{position}: \ [&1, 2, \dots, 52] \\
\end{aligned}$$
We now assume that the deck is well-shuffled, by applying a random permutation $\Pi$ with a discrete uniform distribution to this deck.
Applying the random permutation, $\Pi(i) = j$ means that the card in position $i$ is moved to position $j$. Because the deck was previously in natural order, we also have that it is card label $i$ that is moved to position $j$. Now the order of the deck after the permutation $\Pi$ is applied, assuming the deck was previously in natural order, is now
$$\begin{aligned}
\text{card label}:\  (&\Pi^{-1}(1), \Pi^{-1}(2), \dots, \Pi^{-1}(52)) := (X_1, \dots, X_{52})\\
\text{position}: \ [&1, 2, \dots, 52] \\
\end{aligned}$$
Because $\Pi$ is random, and we do not know the position which card $i$ was moved to, we can define $X_j := \Pi^{-1}(j)$ as the unknown label of the card in the $j$-th position after $\Pi$ has been applied.
Now Ethier (2010) uses a theorem to show how a well-shuffled deck $X_1, \dots, X_{52}$ is "exchangeable, that is, if the cards are permuted in an arbitrary nonrandom way (or even in a random way under certain conditions) the deck will remain well-shuffled."
The example given to illustrate this is computing the probability that the 2nd card drawn from a deck is an ace, after the 1st card has been burned, and placed at the bottom of the deck. This amounts to applying a known permutation to the well-shuffled deck, call it $\sigma \in S_{52}$, which we can define as
$$\sigma(k) = 
\begin{cases}
52 &\text{ if} \quad k =1 \\
k-1 &\text{ if} \quad 1 \leq k \leq 51.
\end{cases}$$
So our new deck ordering after applying $\sigma$ will be
$$\begin{align}
\text{card label}:\  (&\Pi^{-1}(\sigma^{-1}(1)), \Pi^{-1}(\sigma^{-1}(2)), \dots, \Pi^{-1}(\sigma^{-1}(52))) \\
=(&(\sigma \circ \Pi)^{-1}(1), (\sigma \circ \Pi)^{-1}(2), \dots, (\sigma \circ \Pi)^{-1}(52)) \tag{1} \\
\text{position}: \ [&1, 2, \dots, 52]. \\
\end{align}$$
Where I am having difficulty is reconciling this with the conventional definition of exchangeability:

Actually, the notion of exchangeability is more general. If $X_1, \dots, X_N$ are jointly distributed discrete random variables, we say that they are exchangeable if the joint distribution of $X_{\pi(1)}, X_{\pi(2)}, \dots, X_{\pi(N)}$ coincides with that of $X_1, X_2, \dots, X_N$ for all permutations $\pi \in S_N$. For example, if $\Pi$ is as Theorem 11.2.1. and $X_j := \Pi^{-1}(j)
$ for $j = 1, 2, \dots, N$, then $X_1, \dots, X_N$ are exchangeable.

Question.
Following the general definition of exchangeability, if my well shuffled deck is $(X_1, \dots, X_{52})$, then if I apply the known permutation $\sigma \in S_{52}$, then I will have
$$(X_2, X_3, \dots, X_{52}, X_1). \tag{2}$$
If I describe this using a permutation of the indices $\pi \in S_{52}$, then
$$\pi(k)=
\begin{cases}
k+1 &\text{ if} \quad k \in [1, 51] \\
1 &\text{ if} \quad k = 52.
\end{cases}$$
If I 'equate' representations $(1)$ and $(2)$, then this suggests that
$$X_{\pi(k)} = (\sigma \circ \Pi)^{-1}(k).$$
and it also appears that $\pi = \sigma^{-1}$.
I am experiencing confusion between interpreting $\pi$ as permuting indices of the labels of cards and $\sigma$ as permuting the labels themselves. Because on some level, permuting indices of the random variables must be equivalent to permuting the arrangement of the random variables themselves.
What is the distinction between the two ways of seeing the permutations, and also how does this relate to the fact that $\pi = \sigma^{-1}$?

Definitions and theorems from Ethier (2010).
From Ethier (2010), the definition of a deck in natural order is:

Consider a deck of N distinct cards, which for convenience we will assume are labeled $1, 2, \dots N$. For specificity, we also label the positions of the cards in the deck as follows: With the cards face down, the top card in the deck is in position 1, the second card is in position 2, and so on. In particular, when the cards are dealt, the card in position 1 is dealt first.

The definition of a well-shuflled deck is:

In this section, we assume that the deck is well shuffled. More precisely, if $\Pi$ denotes the random permutation of $(1, 2, \dots, N)$ that describes the deck ordering, we assume $\Pi$ to have the discrete uniform distribution. Recall that $\Pi(i) = j$ means that the card in position $i$ is moved to position $j$ by the permutation. If the cards are in natural order $(1, 2, \dots, N)$ initially, then
$$(\Pi^{-1}(1), \dots, \Pi^{-1}(N)) \tag{11.25}$$
is the order of the cards in the deck after $\Pi$ is applied. For example, card $j$ is in position $1$ after the shuffle if $\Pi^{-1}(1)=j$, or equivalently, if $\Pi(j) = 1$, that is, if the card in position $j$ initially, namely card $j$, is moved to position $1$ by the shuffle.

The following is the relevant theorem that a well shuffled deck is exchangeable, and if the cards are permuted in an arbitrary nonrandom way (or even in a random way under certain conditions) the deck will remain well-shuffled:

Theorem 11.2.1. Let $\Pi$ be an $S_N$-valued random variable with the discrete uniform distribution.
(a) If $\pi_1, \pi_2 \in S_N$, then $\pi_1 \circ \Pi$ and $\Pi \circ \pi_2$ have the discrete uniform distribution.
(b) If $\Pi_1$ (resp., $\Pi_2$) is an $S_N$-valued random variable independent of $\Pi$, then $\Pi_1 \circ \Pi$ (resp., $\Pi \circ \Pi_2$) has the discrete uniform distribution.
(c) If $\lambda: S_N \mapsto S_N$ is one-to-one and nonrandom, then $\lambda(\Pi)$ has the discrete uniform distribution.
(d) $\Pi^{-1}$ has the discrete uniform distribution.

